# retrieve closest element from a set of elements

Tags: algorithm, search

I'm experimenting with an idea, where I have following subproblem:

I have a list of size `m` containing tuples of fixed length `n`.

```
[(e11, e12, .., e1n), (e21, e22, .., e2n), ..., (em1, em2, .., emn)]
```

Now, given some random tuple `(t1, t2, .., tn)`, which does not belong to the list, I want to find the closest tuple(s), that belongs to the list.

I use the following distance function (Hamming distance):

```
def distance(A, B):
    total = 0
    for e1, e2 in zip(A, B):
        total += e1 == e2
    return total
```

One option is to use exhaustive search, but this is not sufficient for my problem as the lists are quite large. Other idea, I have come up with, is to first use `kmedoids` to cluster the list and retrieve `K` medoids (cluster centers). For querying, I can determine the closest cluster with `K` calls to distance function. Then, I can search for the closest tuple from that particular cluster. I think it should work, but I am not completely sure, if it is fine in cases the query tuple is on the edges of the clusters.

However, I was wondering, if you have a better idea to solve the problem as my mind is completely blank at the moment. However, I have a strong feeling that there may be a clever way to do it.

Solutions that require precomputing something are fine as long as they bring down the complexity of the query.

Comment: It does not exactly answers the metric you desire, but if you can compare between elemenets, you might want to use a [k-d tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree) to get the closest element (The difference is there is significance to "how far" is it from a dimension, and not only to match the highest possibly number of dimensions)

Comment: i forgot to say, that the elements are comparable, but only exact matches with Hamming distance are meaningful for the task, so unfortunately k-d tree is not suitable.

Comment: See similar questions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8734034/how-to-find-the-closest-pairs-hamming-distance-of-a-string-of-binary-bins-in-r) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/859441/algorithm-to-find-closest-string-using-same-characters).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store a hash table (dictionary/map) that maps from an element (in the tupple) to the tupples it appears in: `hash:element->list<tupple>`.

Now, when you have a new "query", you will need to iterate each of `hash(element)` for each element of the new "query", and find the maximal number of hits.

**pseudo code:**

```
findMax(tuple):
  histogram <- empty map  
  for each element in tuple:
     #assuming hash_table is the described DS from above
     for each x in hash_table[element]: 
         histogram[x]++ #assuming lazy initialization to 0
  return key with highest value in histogram
```

---

An alternative, that does not exactly follow the metric you desired is a [k-d tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree). The difference is k-d tree also take into consideration the "distance" between the elements (and not only equality/inequality). 

k-d trees also require the elements to be comparable.

Comment: A k-d tree should work. Hamming distance is a metric. Partitioning can be done on the basis of equality or not in each dimension. Search of the tree ought to be lower complexity than iterating through the hash table approach.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, I process your ideas for a few minutes and look up the details of k-d tree as I have never quite exactly used it before. Then I will accept the answer.

Comment: @A.Webb: I don't think so, though I never really thought about it - won't it be a problem that if you use only equality/inequality rather then <,=,> you might have `a!=b,b!=c` but `a=c` (The inequality is not transitive)?

Comment: What I had in mind with that statement was strings with a small alphabet where it would be practical to partition each dimension into equivalence classes. (Hamming distance is often done on Hamming spaces - binary strings). I see now this problem is more general -- the number of distinct elements is arbitrary.

Comment: Looks like a [BK-Tree](http://blog.notdot.net/2007/4/Damn-Cool-Algorithms-Part-1-BK-Trees) is more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

If your data is big enough, you may want to create some [inverted indexes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_index) over it.

With a data of **m** vectors of **n** elements.

Data:

```
0: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ...
1: 2, 3, 1, 5, 3, ...
2: 5, 3, 2, 1, 3, ...
3: 1, 2, 1, 5, 3, ...
...
m: m0, ... mn
```

Then you want to get **n** indexes like this:

Index0

```
1: 0, 3
2: 1
5: 2
```

Index1

```
2: 0, 3
3: 3, 3
```

Index2

```
3: 0
1: 1, 3
2: 2
```

...

Then you only search on your indexes to get the tuples that contain any of the query tuple values and find the closest tuple within those.

```
def search(query)
  candidates = []
  for i in range(len(query))
    value = query[i]
    candidates.append(indexes[i][value])

  # find candidates with min distance
  for candidate in candidates
    distance = distance(candidate, query)
    ...
```

The heavy process is creating the indexes, once you built them the search will be really fast.

Comment: Hmm, your solution is similar to @amit's solution, although you clearly state that different positions in tuples need different hash tables, which amit did not explicitly say, but is actually required. However, it seems that your search procedure could be better. You use a list to store possible candidates, which will contain some duplicates and moreover one needs to use distance function explicitly in the end. The way Amit sums the hits for different candidates actually computes the Hamming distance (at least for tuples, that have at least one match).

Comment: Therefore, amits solution also does not need explicit loop to get the candidates with minimal distance (as the ones with minimal distances can be updated during updating counts in the hash tables in the search function). Still, thanks for your input. +1.